# Could the R language function sample be used to do bootstrap resampling?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap

Could the R language function sample be used to do bootstrap resampling?

Does the R language package boot be always loaded to do bootstrap 
  resampling for the purpose of calculating the 99% confidence interval?

Please explain the following R language code with respect to bootstrap resampling.

```
x <- 1:12
# a random permutation 
sample(x)
# bootstrap resampling
-- only if length(x) > 1
sample(x, replace = TRUE)
```

The R program simulates the calculation of a salesman's daily commission 
 and calculates the 95% confidence interval for the mean commission amount.

```
commissionsimul = function(){
  bonus = 0
  commissionamount = 0
  morethan4 = sample(c(1,2),size = 1,replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.4))
  if (morethan4 == 2)
  {
     demand = sample(c(5,6,7,8),1,replace=TRUE,prob=c(.35,.45,.15,.05))
 partnumber=sample(c(1,2,3,4),1,replace=TRUE,prob=c(.40,.35,.20,.05))
 if (partnumber == 1){
    commissionamount = 10
 }
 else if (partnumber == 2){
    commissionamount = 20
 }
 else if (partnumber == 3){
    commissionamount = 25;
 }
     commission = commission + commissionamount * demand
  } 
  return(commission) 
}  
commissionvalues = c()
n = 10000
vals=1:n
for (i in 1:n){
  commissionvalues[i] <- commissionsimul()
}
# remove the duplicate elements
comissionvalues[!duplicated(commissionvalues)]  
sampsize=length(commissionvalues)
for (i in 1:n){
  resampvals=sample(commissionvalues,sampsize,replace=TRUE)
  vals[i]=mean(resampvals)
}
ord=order(vals)  # ascending sort
svals=vals[ord]
ord=order(bonusvalues)
svals[250] # lower 2.5% confidence interval bracket beginning
svals[9750] # upper 2.5% confidence interval bracket beginning

Any help is greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Personally I use `sample` much more often than `boot` library...

Comment: @Tim, Thank you for your excellent comment. May I ask you to see if R language sample is used correctly with resampvals=sample(commissionvalues,sampsize,replace=TRUE) for the purpose of calculating the 95% confidence interval in the R language code I just added at the bottom of my original question ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Could the R language function sample be used to do bootstrap resampling?
```

Yes, `boot`is regularly used for bootstrap resampling.

```
Does the R language package boot be always loaded to do bootstrap resampling for the purpose of calculating the 99% confidence interval?
```

The `boot`package is part of the standard installation of R. If by "loaded" you mean, whether  you need to do something before taking use of it, you have to import it using

```
library(boot)
```

or

```
require(boot)

Please explain the following R language code with respect to bootstrap resampling.
```

`sample(x)` will give you a permutation without replacement. That is not a bootstrap sample. `sample(x, replace=TRUE)`will give you a bootstrap sample of `x`, because replacement is an essential part of bootstrapping.

Comment: This is a great answer. May I ask you to see if R language sample is used correctly  for the purpose of calculating the 95% confidence interval in the R language code I just added at the bottom of my original question ?

Comment: Thanks. I am not going to discuss the second question on your code as the question was put on hold. Try asking that part as a whole new question on Stackoverflow!